# How to extract the hyperlink text from a <a> html tag?

Tags: html, regex, matlab, hyperlink

Given a string containing `'blabla <a href="address">text</a> blabla'`, I want to extract `'text'` from it.
[regexp](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) doc suggests `'<(\w+).*>.*</\1>'` expression, but it extracts the whole `<a> ... </a>` thing.
Of course I can continue using `strfind` like this:

```
line = 'blabla <a href="address">text</a> blabla';
atag = regexp(line,'<(\w+).*>.*</\1>','match', 'once');
from = strfind(atag, '>');
to = strfind(atag, '<');
text = atag((from(1)+1):(to(2)-1))
```

, but, can I use another expression to find `text` at once?

Comment: Wrap the `.*` (note you should actually use `.*?` in case you have multiple `<a></a>` pairs in the string) in `()` and you can get its match in the second element of the `tok` array if you use `[atag,tok] = regexp(line,'<(\w+).*>(.*?)</\1>','match','tokens');`

Comment: Did the `extractHTMLText` was helpful? did you wanted only regex solution?

Comment: @DavidS, well `extractHTMLText` was introduced in 2018a, while I'm running 2016a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `extractHTMLText` function in Matlab, you can read about it in the following [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/textanalytics/ref/htmltree.extracthtmltext.html).
Example that get the desired output:

```
line = 'blabla <a href="address">text</a> blabla';
l = split(extractHTMLText(line), ' ');
l{2}
```

If you don't want to use a built in function you could use *regex* as **Nick** suggested.

```
line = 'blabla <a href="address">text</a> blabla';
[atag,tok] = regexp(line,'<(\w+).*>(.*?)</\1>','match','tokens'); 
t = tok(1,1){1};
t{2}
```

and you'll get the desired output

Comment: Thank you David. I finally used `<a.*>(.*?)</a>` since there're tons of `<bla>`s in there. Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/lPKr14/4).

Comment: @saastn Very elegant; and regarding the `extractHTMLText` you are tight it was introduced in 19' I didn't know you're working on 16' version

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a `Group`.

Update of your pattern will be something like this:

```regex
<(\w+).*>(.*)<\/\1>
```

---

and this one include all tags:

```regex
<.*>(.*)<.*>
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lPKr14/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery try this. No Regex required. But this might negatively impact performance if the DOM is hefty.

```
$jqueryobj = $(line);
var text = $jqueryobj.find("a").text();
```